# Latching a Variable?

Tags: python

So here is what I have pieced together from both pygames and xboxdrv and a few other tutorials on how to supply power out from the GPIO pins on RPi. I am trying to use an xbox controller connected to a RPi. What is below is the code to turn an LED on when the "A" button is pressed. This works just fine for me.

When the Value == 1 the light will blink on, as soon as the button is released the Value == 0 which has no coding on it currently.

What I want to do though is for the LED to stay powered when "A" is pressed and stay lit when the button is released, but when the "A" button is pressed again for the LED to turn off.

```
def controlCallBack(xboxControlId, value):
    print "Control Id = {}, Value = {}".format(xboxControlId, value)
            if xboxControlId == 6 and value == 1:
                pin = 7 
                GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
                GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
                GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
                time.sleep(.05) 
                GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(.05)
                GPIO.cleanup()
```

Any help with this will be much appreciated, I am very new to Python and programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
led_powered = False

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)    

def teardown():
    GPIO.cleanup()

def power_led():
    GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)
    global led_powered 
    led_powered = True


def unpower_led():
    GPIO.output(7, GPIO.LOW)
    global led_powered 
    led_powered = False

def controlCallBack(xboxControlId, value):
    print "Control Id = {}, Value = {}".format(xboxControlId, value)
    if xboxControlId == 6 and value == 1:
        if led_powered:
            unpower_led()
        else:
            power_led()
```

Call setup() at the beginning of your program and teardown() at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an object-oriented version of user2804197's code:

```
class Led(object):
    LED_PIN = 7

    def __init__(self):
        self.powered = False
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(self.LED_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

    def __del__(self):
        GPIO.cleanup()

    def power(self):
        GPIO.output(self.LED_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
        self.powered = True

    def unpower(self):
        GPIO.output(self.LED_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
        self.powered = False

    def toggle(self):
        if self.powered:
            self.unpower()
        else:
            self.power()

led = Led()

def controlCallBack(xboxControlId, value):
    print "Control Id = {}, Value = {}".format(xboxControlId, value)
    if xboxControlId == 6 and value == 1:
        led.toggle()
```

You can also call `led.power()` and `led.unpower()` directly.